# Create a proxy for an specific instance of an object in clojure

Tags: object, proxy, clojure, instance

I am trying to create a proxy object that adds some functionality to some of the methods of an object, using a closure (let / proxy) I ca do the thing, unfortunately I hava to re write ALL of the methods from the original object o I get an UnsupportedOpretationException here is an example:
;; the real object

```
(def realcon (java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/test"))


(def con 
    (let [msg "FG>"
          xcon rcon]
        (proxy [java.sql.Connection] []
            (createStatement []
                (println msg) ;; access to closure context !
                (.createStatement xcon)))))

(def stmt (.createStatement con))
;;output FG>

(def rs (.executeQuery stmt "select count(*) from serie_sat"))
```

If I invoque any other method from java.sql.Connection I get UnsupportedOperationException I can do by hand the proxying of ALL methods but may be there is a beter way!.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative using `reify` instead of `proxy` since, according to the [docs](http://clojure.org/datatypes), it's "preferable in all cases where its constraints are not prohibitive."

```
(defmacro override-delegate
  [type delegate & body]
  (let [d (gensym)
        overrides (group-by first body)
        methods (for [m (.getMethods (resolve type))
                      :let [f (-> (.getName m)
                                symbol
                                (with-meta {:tag (-> m .getReturnType .getName)}))]
                      :when (not (overrides f))
                      :let [args (for [t (.getParameterTypes m)]
                                   (with-meta (gensym) {:tag (.getName t)}))]]
                  (list f (vec (conj args 'this))
                    `(. ~d ~f ~@(map #(with-meta % nil) args))))]
    `(let [~d ~delegate]
       (reify ~type ~@body ~@methods))))


;; Modifying your example slightly...
(def realcon (java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/test"))
(def con 
  (let [msg "FG>"]
    (override-delegate java.sql.Connection realcon
      (createStatement [this]
        (println msg)
        (.createStatement realcon)))))
```

The `override-delegate` macro expects the body to contain the `reify` specs of the methods you wish to override. Any you don't override will be invoked on the delegate. All `reify` specs generated by the macro will include type hints for each method's arguments and return value.

There is a caveat with my implementation: it only checks for method *names* in the `body`, ignoring argument arity/type for overloaded methods. So in the example above, where the `java.sql.Connection` interface provides multiple `createStatement` overloads, none of those that accept arguments will be defined for `con`. It wouldn't be too difficult to extend the macro to account for overloads, but when I need this behavior, I typically have to override all of them anyway.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I ended up needing support for multiple interfaces, which was a relatively minor change from your code. After pluralizing the first argument name, just `s/(.getMethods (resolve type))/(mapcat #(.getMethods (resolve %)) types)/` and `s/~type/~@types/`.

Answer (score 3):

I have just written the most ridiculous macro of my life to support this functionality. There might be a simpler way -- if I can think of one, I will certainly post it -- but this gave me a cool, trippy feeling and actually seems to work, so... here goes.

*Edit: Here's a simpler way; define a function returning a regular `proxy` which delegates all methods (write it by hand or create it automatically -- the code of `delegating-proxy` contains a way of doing that), the use `update-proxy` on individual instances to replace just the methods which need replacing. This is clearly less cool than the crazy macro, so the latter shall remain below.*

Here's the new, simplified approach (still not extremely clear due to some issues with the position parameter count limit and varargs):

```
;;; delegates all methods
(defmacro delegating-proxy [o class-and-ifaces ctor-args]
  (let [oname (gensym)
        impls (->> class-and-ifaces
                   (map resolve)
                   (mapcat #(.getDeclaredMethods ^Class %))
                   (group-by #(.getName ^java.lang.reflect.Method %))
                   (vals)
                   (map (fn delegating-impls [^java.lang.reflect.Method ms]
                          (let [mname (symbol (.getName ^java.lang.reflect.Method (first ms)))
                                arity-groups (partition-by #(count (.getParameterTypes ^java.lang.reflect.Method %)) ms)
                                max-arity (max-key #(count (.getParameterTypes ^java.lang.reflect.Method %)) ms)]
                            `(~mname
                              ~@(remove
                                 nil?
                                 (map (fn [agroup]
                                        (let [param-types (.getParameterTypes ^java.lang.reflect.Method (first agroup))
                                              vararg? (and (seq param-types) (or (.isArray ^Class (last param-types)) (<= 20 (count param-types))))
                                              arity  ((if vararg? dec identity) (count param-types))
                                              params (vec (repeatedly arity gensym))
                                              params (if vararg? (conj params '& (gensym)) params)]
                                          (when-not (and vararg? (not= arity max-arity))
                                            (list params `(. ~oname (~mname ~@params))))))
                                      arity-groups)))))))]
    `(let [~oname ~o]
       (proxy ~class-and-ifaces ~ctor-args ~@impls))))
```

A demo:

```
user> (def p (delegating-proxy (fn [& args] :foo) [clojure.lang.IFn] []))
#'user/p
user> (update-proxy p {"applyTo" (fn [& args] :bar)})
#<Object$IFn$4c646ebb user.proxy$java.lang.Object$IFn$4c646ebb@1c445f88>
user> (p 1)
:foo
user> (apply p (seq [1]))
:bar
```

---

*Edit: the original macro follows.*

First, a demo:

```
user> (.invoke (delegating-proxy (fn [x y] (prn x y))
                 [clojure.lang.IFn] []
                 (invoke [x] :foo))
               :bar)
:foo
user> (.invoke (delegating-proxy (fn [x y] (prn x y))
                 [clojure.lang.IFn] []
                 (invoke [x] :foo))
               :bar :quux)
:bar :quux
nil
```

`delegating-proxy` accepts an object to which it delegates when called upon to execute a method not explicitly implemented followed by the regular `proxy` arguments.

Second, the code. I think it's safe to assume there are various imperfections lurking in there. Actually the general shape of it is right out there; no lurking. If it's sufficiently useful to someone, it could probably be tested & improved into some degree of assured robustness.

[The Gist](https://gist.github.com/1715851) is somewhat easier to read.

```
(defmacro delegating-proxy [o class-and-ifaces ctor-args & impls]
  (let [oname (gensym)]
    (letfn [(delegating-impls [^java.lang.reflect.Method ms]
              (let [mname (symbol (.getName ^java.lang.reflect.Method (first ms)))
                    arity-groups (partition-by #(count (.getParameterTypes ^java.lang.reflect.Method %)) ms)
                    max-arity (max-key #(count (.getParameterTypes ^java.lang.reflect.Method %)) ms)]
                `(~mname
                  ~@(remove
                     nil?
                     (map (fn [agroup]
                            (let [param-types (.getParameterTypes ^java.lang.reflect.Method (first agroup))
                                  vararg? (and (seq param-types) (or (.isArray ^Class (last param-types)) (<= 20 (count param-types))))
                                  arity  ((if vararg? dec identity) (count param-types))
                                  params (vec (repeatedly arity gensym))
                                  params (if vararg? (conj params '& (gensym)) params)]
                              (when-not (and vararg? (not= arity max-arity))
                                (list params `(. ~oname (~mname ~@params))))))
                          arity-groups)))))
            (combine-impls [eimpls dimpls]
              (map (fn [e d]
                     (let [e (if (vector? (second e))
                               (list (first e) (next e))
                               e)]
                       (list* (first e) (concat (next e) (next d)))))
                   eimpls
                   dimpls))]
      (let [klass   (resolve (first class-and-ifaces))
            methods (->> class-and-ifaces
                         (map resolve)
                         (mapcat #(.getDeclaredMethods ^Class %)))
            eimpl-specs (set (map (juxt first (comp count second)) impls))
            rm-fn   (fn rm-fn [^java.lang.reflect.Method m]
                      (contains? eimpl-specs [(symbol (.getName m)) (count (.getParameterTypes m))]))
            dimpls  (->> methods
                         (remove rm-fn)
                         (remove #(let [mods (.getModifiers ^java.lang.reflect.Method %)]
                                    (or (java.lang.reflect.Modifier/isPrivate mods)
                                        (java.lang.reflect.Modifier/isProtected mods))))
                         (sort-by #(.getName ^java.lang.reflect.Method %))
                         (partition-by #(.getName ^java.lang.reflect.Method %))
                         (map delegating-impls))
            dimpl-names (set (map first dimpls))
            eimpl-names (set (map first eimpl-specs))
            {eonly false eboth true} (group-by (comp boolean dimpl-names first) impls)
            {donly false dboth true} (group-by (comp boolean eimpl-names first) dimpls)
            all-impls (concat eonly donly (combine-impls eboth dboth))]
        `(let [~oname ~o]
           (proxy ~class-and-ifaces ~ctor-args
             ~@all-impls))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much I lerned a lot by seeing your answer, then I found some minor errors.

1. In the function delegating-impls, the parameter is an array of Method objects do the type cast is wrong. This means that max-arity is not a number and does not contain the bigest arity.

This took me to understand the code that has to do with de varargs. and realized that the var arg constructor in java (...) presets the las parameter as a array, the problem is that is the object has one method with for example 2 parameters and an other method with one parameter followed by a vararg (...) the we end up with 2 methods of the same arity, the code of delegating-proxy macro never enters the:
(when-not (and vararg? (not= arity max-arity)) because max-arity is no a number! so the proxy object omits any method with an array as the last parameter.

This took me to make a rewrite of the delegating-proxy and I ended up with the folowing code that work fine if there are no vararg (...) parameters, otherwise this methods will not be covered by the proxy implementation.

Here is the code:

`` (defmacro instance-proxy [obj mtd-re-filter pre-func post-func]
    (let [cls (class (eval obj))
          interfaces (.getInterfaces cls)
          ifaces (into [] (map #(symbol (.getName %)) interfaces))
          oname (gensym)
          info (gensym)
          impls (->> ifaces
                     (map resolve)
                     (mapcat #(.getDeclaredMethods ^Class %))
                     (group-by #(.getName ^java.lang.reflect.Method %))
                     (vals)
                     (map (fn delegating-impls [ms] ;; ms is an array of "Method" objects
                              (let [mname (symbol (.getName ^java.lang.reflect.Method (first ms)))
                                    arity-groups (partition-by #(count (.getParameterTypes ^java.lang.reflect.Method %)) ms)]
                                  `(~mname
                                    ~@(remove
                                       nil?
                                       (map (fn [agroup]
                                                (let [param-types (.getParameterTypes ^java.lang.reflect.Method (first agroup))
                                                      arity  (count param-types)
                                                      vararg? (and
                                                                  (seq param-types)
                                                                  (.isArray ^Class (last param-types)))
                                                      params (vec (repeatedly arity gensym))]
                                                    (when-not vararg?
                                                        (if (re-matches mtd-re-filter (name mname))
                                                            (list params
                                                                `(swap! ~info ~pre-func)
                                                             `(let [result# (. ~oname (~mname ~@params))]
                                                                  (swap! ~info ~post-func)
                                                                  result#))
                                                            (list params `(. ~oname (~mname ~@params)))))))
                                            arity-groups)))))))]
        `(let [~oname ~obj
               ~info (atom {})]
             (proxy ~ifaces [] ~@impls))))

;;The code abobe is used like so:

(defn pre-test [m]
        (println "ejecutando pre")
        (assoc m :t0 (System/currentTimeMillis)))

(defn post-test [m]
        (println "ejecutando post " m)
        (let [now (System/currentTimeMillis)
              mm (assoc m :t1 now :delta (- now (:t0 m)))]
              (println mm)
              mm))

(def rcon (java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/test"))

(def pcon (instance-proxy rcon #"prepareStatement" pre-test post-test))

(def stmt (.prepareStatement pcon "select * from SERIE_SAT"))



;;ejecutando pre
;;ejecutando post  {:t0 1330046744318}
;;{:delta 3, :t1 1330046744321, :t0 1330046744318}
;;#'mx.interware.analyzer.driver/stmt

;;Here we obtain the statistics in a non-intrusive way wich was the objective of this code ! ``

Thats all for now and thanks again for the very clever macro !

Saludos